# How do I get the id for a <tr> in when using jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am adding a button that will "approve" all rows in the table (call a URL to process the record). I generate the table then attach the DataTable to the prefilled table. On each tr I have the id number of the record.

```
<tr id="11309742">
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="11309743">
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
            $.each(table.fnGetData(), function (i, row) {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $.get(myUrl, { id: id },
                    function (json) {
                        if (json.Sucess) {
                            // TODO remove from the page
                        }
                    }, "json");
            });
```

`var id = $(this).attr("id");` worked before I switched to the datatable plugin (and I know it won't work now). Everything I have seen is either setting the id or getting the index from a click in the row. How do I get that `id` attribute in a loop?

Comment: if this is still the html element tr, you can just use this.id

Comment: any reason why you're using `fnGetData()`? are you going to send the row contents in your `$.get` call?

Comment: All I need is the id of the record. I think I figured out my problem. I'll post answer once confirmed working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.fnGetData()`, I should have used `.fnGetNodes()`.

```
            $.each(table.fnGetNodes(), function (i, row) {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $.get(myUrl, { id: id },
                    function (json) {
                        if (json.Sucess) {
                            //table.fnDeleteRow(i);
                        }
                    }, "json");
            });
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: instead of `table.fnGetNodes()` you can also do `table.$('tr')`